# RunAs authentication not injected into controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I noticed that when I replace the Authentication object in RunAsManager, the resolvable controller method arguments (`Authentication`, `Principal`, and `@AuthenticationPrincipal`) ignore the new Authentication object and receive the original one.

**Examples** (all 4 methods are in the same controller)

This resolves to the correct (runAs) Authentication:

```
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_WORKFLOW", "RUN_AS_USER"})
@PostMapping("/testRunAs")
public ResponseEntity<Result> testRunAs() {
    Authentication authentication = 
              SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    log.debug(authentication.getPrincipal().toString());  // correct
    ...
```

These resolve to the wrong (original) Authentication:

```
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_WORKFLOW", "RUN_AS_USER"})
@PostMapping("/testRunAs1")
public ResponseEntity<Result> testRunAs1(Authentication authentication) {
    log.debug(authentication.getPrincipal().toString());  // wrong
    ...
```

---

```
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_WORKFLOW", "RUN_AS_USER"})
@PostMapping("/testRunAs2")
public ResponseEntity<Result> testRunAs2(Principal principal) {
    log.debug(principal.toString());  // wrong
    ...
```

---

```
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_WORKFLOW", "RUN_AS_USER"})
@PostMapping("/testRunAs3")
public ResponseEntity<Result> testRunAs3(@AuthenticationPrincipal User u) {
    log.debug(u.toString());  // wrong
    ...
```

How is this possible?

- The `resolveArgument` method in Spring's `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` clearly does

  ```
  Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
          .getAuthentication();
  ```
- The `runAs` evaluation takes place in `beforeInvocation` of Spring's `AbstractSecurityInterceptor`

Looks like the argumentResolver executes before the runAs replacement, although I'm not able to confirm that via debugger (somehow not able to hit a breakpoint in `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver`)

Is this expected behaviour?

*Note: I am on Spring Security 4.2.3.RELEASE*